# Require field in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an HTML form in Rails like

```
<form name="input" action="jump">
  Title: <input type="text" name="title"> 
  <input type="button" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I want `title` to be a required field (i.e. the user cannot leave it blank), and I'd like to verify that in the Rails `jump` controller. Note that `title` is not a field in the model; it's just a form field that's going to be processed within the controller.

How can I do the verification, and display the error to the user elegantly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use active model to handle things:

class SomeModel << ActiveModel

```
#some Model
attr_accessor :title
validates_presence_of :title
```

end

The benefits for this is that you can throw validation and handling of displaying errors on to Rails.

The other way is to do it handling things purely on the controller side:

```
if  params[:title].present?

  ...#do something

else

  ...#do something else
```

Tis a less than elegant approach however.  If you go this route, I would suggest creating a ruby object to at least moving logic out of the controller.

Comment: But is it worth dealing with a model here? Since I'm not submitting it to any model...

Comment: ah, the wording pointed me to assume that it was just an added field to a model.

Comment: Just used this answer today on Rails 4 - still relevant, although attr_accessor doesn't appear to be needed. +1

Answer (score 4):

you actually can use HTML5 tech to apply on that

```
 <input type="text" name="usrname" required="required" />
```

beside, you can use a gem 'client-side validation'
the github is here
https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations

I suggest you use the gem...pretty awesome :D

Comment: The Client Side Validations gem is no longer being maintained.

Answer (score 3):

you have 2 options, you can make a validate in frontend and the backend, it is good to do both:

Frontend

```
<%= f.text_field ..other attributes... required: true %>
```

Backend

you have 2 options again

in your model

```
validates :title, :presence
```

or in your controller you can check with this

```
if  params[:title].present?
    #your logic
end
```